# SSH Tunnelling troubleshooting

Tags: ssh, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

I am using git bash on my windows computer. I am trying to set up an SSH tunnel so I can access databases within MySQL Query Browser. The following works:

```
> ssh root@staging
```

This uses my public key and gives me access over SSH successfully, but when I try this:

```
> ssh -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 \ root@staging
```

I get this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this problem? I have tried replacing my hostname "staging" to the actual IP address, but no luck there as well. I have also tried the server IP address in place of 127.0.0.1.

Here is a snippet of sshd_config, which seems most important:

```
#AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you connect using

```
ssh -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 \ root@staging
```

the '\' escapes the following space. therefore ssh is trying to connect with a username of ' root' not 'root'.

try without the \ and if it still fails add -vvv into the command line which provides some debugging output then update you're question with it so we can have a look.